# Enabling readerQuotas on WCF GZip Encoder Custom Binding

Tags: .net, wcf, compression, gzip, wcf-binding

I have enabled compression of my WCF service by implementing the sample [GZip encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138373%28VS.90%29.aspx) featured on on MSDN and everything is working great, however now need to transfer my reader quotas across to this binding, as I previously had these customised when I was using `wsHttpBinding`.

This is my GZip binding as declared in my `Web.config` of the wcf service:

```
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="BufferedHttpCompressionBinding" closeTimeout="00:00:15"
      openTimeout="00:00:15" receiveTimeout="00:00:15" sendTimeout="00:00:15">
      <gzipMessageEncoding innerMessageEncoding="textMessageEncoding">
      </gzipMessageEncoding>
      <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
        maxBufferSize="2147483647">
        <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
      </httpTransport>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

As you can see without the reader quotas, now here are the readerQuotas that I would like to add:

```
<readerQuotas
              maxDepth="64"
              maxStringContentLength="1048576"
              maxArrayLength="1048576"
              maxBytesPerRead="1048576"
              maxNameTableCharCount="1048576" />
```

I have tried inserting this node as a child of the `<binding />` element, and also I saw an example online of it between the `<gzipMessageEncoding />` element, neither of the two work for me returning an error:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized element 'readerQuotas'.
```

Any thoughts? Is it possible to use reader quotas with custom bindings? I imagine it would have to be, but might this be a class change, or a simple way to get it going through config?  Hopefully some WCF whiz can help :)

Many thanks,
Graham.

Comment: might try using the service config editor - not sure if it supports custom bindings or not, but worth a shot :)

Comment: Thanks, we had a look in here, it seems it only lists the very base binding fields, no fields for reader quotas can be set :(

Comment: have you figured this out yet? i suspect with the amount of time that has passed you found something. what was the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/633c5dc8-c134-40c9-9dfc-41a4b1cd3279/

You have to modify GZipMessageEncodingElement and GZipMessageEncodingBindingElement to expose readerQuotas...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this programmatically:

```
var gzipBindingElement = new GZipMessageEncodingBindingElement();
myBinding.ReaderQuotas.CopyTo((TextMessageEncodingBindingElement)gzipBindingElement.InnerMessageEncodingBindingElement).ReaderQuotas);
```